# Producing images with subpixel shift in region of interest

Tags: image-processing, matlab, motion-estimation

Let's say for a zebra image, and at certain pixel location, I would like to makes it "vibrate/warp" to and fro in horizontal direction at a certain frequencies in a sequence of images of time `t`, with subpixel shift. The circled area is the most significant area that I intended to simulate the vibration. Those images will be mainly used for synthetic motion estimation.

[image]

In MATLAB, the the zebra image can be produced using the following code:

```
m=75;
n=75;
stripe_px=1;
single_pattern=[ones(m,stripe_px),zeros(n,stripe_px)];
zebra=repmat(single_pattern,[1 ceil(n/stripe_px*2)]);
zebra=zebra(:,1:n);
```

The magnitude of the subpixel shift indicates by this map below:

[image]

Also can be produce by MATLAB code:

```
X=repmat(1:m,[n 1]);
Y=repmat((1:n)',[1 m]);
Shape=0.04*( ((((X/m)-0.75).^2).*X) - ((((Y/n)-0.75).^2).*Y) );
```

Based on the information that I currently have, what's my next step? I was looking at `imwarp` ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html#inputarg_D)), but I'm not sure if it can shift local pixels, where usually it was meant for whole image transform. And its usage is very vague for me. A simple pseudocode to depict what I'm trying to achieve would be:

```
omega=3;
T=30;
Fs=20;
dt=1/Fs;
for t=0:dt:T
    vibrate_im=(zebra + Shape) + sin(omega*t);
end
```

Can a wavelet transform be used for this subtle pixel shifting? If so how do I manipulate its coefficients?

Appreciate any input and help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use image processing toolbox, but I would look at `interp2()`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to distill your question down to a 1-d problem. Does this "moving sine" do ~what you want to do?

```
t = 0:50;
f = (1/4)/5;
x = sin(2*pi*f*t);
nsteps = 50;
figure(1), 
clf
ylim([-1 1])
xlim([0 nsteps])
stepvect = linspace(0,3,nsteps);
stepvect = [stepvect stepvect((end-1):-1:2)];
for step = 1:length(stepvect)
    y = interp1(t, x, t+stepvect(step)*sin(pi*t/50), 'linear');
    plot(t, y)
    grid on
    drawnow;
end
```